# How to get the list box item text once it selected in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, listbox

> I want to perform **Jquery AutoComplete**. My Autocomplete coding is working fine. But **AutoComplete should work when user select the particular listbox item**

[image: This is output window]

you can see one listbox and one text box. I want autocomplete should work when user select the **StoreID item**.

**Jquery Code**

```
//AUTO COMPLETE
var autoSelectedField = $("#FilterField option:selected").text(); 
if (autoSelectedField === 'StoreID') {
    alert(autoSelectedField);
    $('#txtFilterValue').autocomplete({
        source: 'AutoCompleteHandler.ashx'
    });
}
```

**Autocomplete code**

```
public class AutoCompleteHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //string selectName = context.Request["columnName"] ?? "";
        string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";

        List<string> listSelectedColumn = new List<string>();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQMatajerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("JCF_ac_getItemLookupCode", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@storeid",
                    Value = term
                });

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                listSelectedColumn.Add(rdr["StoreCode"].ToString());
            }

        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listSelectedColumn));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> The **Autocomplete should work when list item is selected**.

Comment: add an else condition document.getElementById("txtFilterValue").autocomplete="off"

Comment: @VinodLouis can convert it into jquery?

Comment: $('#txtFilterValue').attr("autocomplete","off")

Comment: @VinodLouis Did you understand my question completely?.. I want to perform autocomplete when **user click the listbox item**

Comment: you need to handle this on change listbox item thus on off autocomplete or as answered return data from autocomplete only on that condition

Comment: @mohamedfaisal: If i am not wrong you need to show different autocomplete result with every listitem selection. On selecting item from fields your filter value should fetch relevant output.  Is this what you are looking for? In your current case it's fetching all listitem result.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal **Exactly you are right**

Comment: @mohamedfaisal: So, you can do a thing just some ID as param to `AutoCompleteHandler.ashx` and from backend just filter out necessary data based on ID check. Either user **Select Case** or **LINQ**.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal yes, can you tell me how to pass param to `AutoCompleteHandler.ashx` by code?.

Comment: Please share your `AutoCompleteHandler.ashx` code in your above code. That will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what I mentioned in your (mohamed faisal) post as a comment this is the only way I came up with. Please notify if found any issue.

> jQuery Autocomplete

```
$('#txtFilterValue').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'AutoCompleteHandler.ashx',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    value : autoSelectedField
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
 });
```

---

> C# Code

```
 string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
 // Mention following code below above line.
 string value = context.Request["value"] ?? "";
```

Comment: this is the answer `//AUTO COMPLETE
    var autoSelectedField = $("#FilterField option:selected").text();

    $('#txtFilterValue').autocomplete({
        source: 'AutoCompleteHandler.ashx?selectName=' + autoSelectedField
    });`

Comment: Does this meets your requirement? If you can access `selectName` on server then this will help you out in filtering desired result.

Comment: Welcome, feels good to see your problem is now solved. Pleasure helping you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#StoreID").on('change', function () {
  var storeItems = $("#FilterField option:selected").text();
  $("#txtFilterValue").autocomplete({
      source: storeItems,
      autoFocus: true
      });
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple, I didn't get that before,

```
//AUTO COMPLETE
var autoSelectedField = $("#FilterField option:selected").text();

$('#txtFilterValue').autocomplete({
    source: 'AutoCompleteHandler.ashx?selectName=' + autoSelectedField
});
```

> pass the value of selected list item and filter it back end code as @Suprabhat Biswal told

Answer (score 0):

you can catch select event by adding the 'select' parameter to the autocomplete function. something like this:

```
$(autoselect_field).autocomplete({
select: function (event, ui){
if($(autoselect_field).value=='Store_ID'){
//do something}
});
```